# How Can I Use The Dynamics AX services in android?

Tags: android, web-services, service, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

when Create services in Dynamic AX ,I Get Link.
I wont Use this services in android ,
How Can I use this link to connect the android app to Dynamics AX ??

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

- Expose your services via http(s) endpoint - this option is useful only if your (Android) clients have access to that network (VPN or publicly visible/DMZ)
- Use Azure Service bus to relay communication between client and server - You can follow [Microsoft Dynamics AX Services and Windows Azure Service Bus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aif/archive/2013/04/29/aif-windows-azure-service-bus-adapter.aspx) guideline

Comment: Thank u for reply ,,
and really i have https endpoint |and can i access from anywhere